# Angular front-end for a complex web ordering platform?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, single-page-application

We're planning to re-write a legacy B2B ordering platform, which also includes some inventory management functionality, user management, reporting, etc.

It's a multi-tenant system, where a lot of the aspects are client-based, such as features, visibility to page elements, various literals across the application, themes, etc. New clients and features are constantly being added and updated.

We're going to be using .NET Core for the backend.

Does Angular make sense for such an application, or would a traditional MPA approach be better?

The concern is that making it a true SPA would make it unnecessarily complex to develop and maintain.

We've considered a hybrid approach, but many claim that it negates all the benefits of an SPA?  How is that so?  We'd still get the benefits of streamlined ajax operations, materials, components, etc.

Comment: `The concern is that making it a true SPA would make it unnecessarily complex.` How so?

Comment: What is the core impetus for the re-write? That should be the core question answered - it will also guide your decisions to however you choose to implement to achieve that goal. It will also make it painfully clear that _opinions_ about a hybrid approach negating whatever SPA benefits are to be had are just _opinions_, nothing more.

Comment: It’s very spaghetti-ish, doesn’t adhere to any design pattern, backend logic seeping info views, etc.  It’s getting harder and harder to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

As you are saying that your B2B ordering platform also have inventory management, user management etc like modules of a system. In my suggestion should go with any front-end framework like `Angular` or `React`. The reason i am suggesting this , because you have inventory management, user management modules also and surely these modules will have a user experience like an admin panel where user can manage their inventory and users etc etc. So for these kind of admin portals, reporting front-end framework plays a vital role in increasing response time, great user experience without any latency and also they offer robust development rather than writing stuff in vanilla javascript or jquery. And i will suggest `Angular`. Because angular offers very huge amount of features, plugins, packages through which you can develop your front-end very quickly and also you can manage your code base in a very modular way.

For example while in reporting you will need export data to csv, print pdfs etc etc so angular have a lot of packages , plugins that does these stuff in a very handy and easy way. So you can done your app with less effort by using angular.